# How to create page feature similar to msword, wordpad or page software(mac) using WPF and C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I have struggling with this issue since long time. I am working of a project in which there is requirement to create pages similar to msword or wordpad or page software(mac). In the mentioned softwares, user can able to type text and once the text reaches to the bottom, a new page appears below it. User continues typing in next page.

I could not able to figure out how to achieve this. I am developing this software using c# and WPF.

Any guidance will be helpful. Thanks in advance. Hope you understand my requirement. So far, I guess, the pages must be similar to iframes in website design. Anyways, any guidance will be helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you need MDI like UI.
Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051601/how-to-implement-mdi-in-a-wpf-application) or google "MDI UI in WPF"

Comment: Thanks....this response is truely helpful.