# How to seta child window moveable only inside the parent window in WPF?

Tags: wpf

```
 private void Button_2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     Views.Window1 win1 = new Views.Window1();
     win1.Show();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in Multiple Document Interface (MDI) support available in WPF. There are some third-party solutions that you can try out though:

[How to implement mdi in a WPF application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051601/how-to-implement-mdi-in-a-wpf-application)